# DB2 Unrecognized JDBC type: -9. ERRORCODE=-4228, SQLSTATE=null

Tags: database, jdbc, db2, websphere, db2-luw

Is anyone familiar with this error:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10271][10296][4.19.26] Unrecognized JDBC type: -9. ERRORCODE=-4228, SQLSTATE=null
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hb.m(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gp.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gp.setObject(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.setObject(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:2476)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:351)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:217)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:145)
```

The current version of my DB2 Database is 10.5.5.

I am using Websphere Application Server (WAS) v.8.5.5 and my JDBC providers use db2jcc4.jar v.4.19.26.

I placed Generic JVM Arguments in WAS which is - `-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and then this error occurred.

Is there something wrong with the DB2 JDBC jars or it is not compatible with my database?

Comment: Looks like at least one of your statement parameters has a data type that has no SQL equivalent.

Comment: JDBC type -9 is `NVARCHAR`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR

Comment: You stack contains Spring framework, may you be using an rather older version? There was a [fixed issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4465) resembling this.

Comment: Is this an issue about the DB2 JDBC jar that I am using or should I update the java version/spring jar of my Websphere Application Sever?

Comment: You may try upgrading Spring to 2.5.2 (reported as the fix version in above mentioned link) if you're using an older version of Spring

Comment: I'm currently using spring version 2.5.6.

Comment: I had this error when trying to insert a null value in a DB2 non-nullable column using spring jdbcTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are really sending the right type of values to the proc. Generally this happens when you send wrong type of value, could be you are sending CharacterSequence for a Character input value to the proc